# Graph single equation on calculator

Tags: calculator

Just got a new  Casio fx-9750gII and just wondering, since you can store up to 20 functions, how do I choose to only graph a specific one at a time? And also to choose witch one to make a table with, get statistics on, etc.

If you haven't owned this model, but you're good with calculators, here's the manual if you need it:

http://support.casio.com/pdf/004/fx-9750GII_Soft_E.pdf

Chapter 5 discusses graphing but nothing about my problem. It seems that all Casio calculators have identical graphing programs, so if you know how to do it on any Casio, most likely it will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You hit "sel" on the F1 button to add/remove the equation from the graph or other programs